# How to render Menu level 1 and 2 always others if parent selected with simple navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with SimpleNavigation-gem on rails;

My Menu display looks like this: Top - level (level 1) on top of the page (thats why it is called top level, I think)

toplevel has 3 items: left, right and legal (at the bottom ;-))

all have some submenus

what I already got is:

A toplevel menu, only showing level 1 ie 3 items.

a menu on the left, showing only 'menu left' items and same for the other two.

All is fine as long i '`expand: all`', but i dont want to have *all* expanded, level 3 should only be here if level2 is selected. so what I need is '`expand: all_to_level_2`'

if I use `level: (1..2)` i get what it says level 1 & 2 but not level 3 if parent is selected

any ideas?